# How to create a mini image gallery using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I've been trying to create a mini image gallery which has an img tag for the main picture called "defaultPic" and another two img tags for the sub images called "subPic1" and "subPic2". So basically the default picture is subPic1, what I want to happen is when the user click subPic2, the image in defaultPic should be replaced by subPic2 vice versa. Here is the image of the rendered html:

[image]

The bigger box is the default picture meanwhile the smaller one's are subPic1 and subPic2. I've tried adding an onclick event to the sub images that when clicked, it will retrieve the image source and will be passed on to the default picture. But when I tried clicking lets say subPic2, the onclick event is not firing and nothing happens. Kindly help me on solving this one or provide better solutions to achieve the same goal.

Here is the html script:

```js
function getImage1(){
  var img = document.getElementById("subPic1").src;
  document.getElementById("defaultPic").src = img;
}

function getImage2(){
  var img = document.getElementById("subPic2").src;
  document.getElementById("defaultPic").src = img;
}
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#defaultPic {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

#subPic1 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

#subPic2 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
<title>TEST</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
<script src="Image1.js"></script>
<script src="Image2.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <img id="defaultPic" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" /><br/>
  <img id="subPic1" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50" onclick="getImage1()"/><br/>
  <img id="subPic2" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50" onclick="getImage2()"/>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its working fine.. check again, below is the snippet of your code

```js
function getImage1(){
var img = document.getElementById("subPic1").src;
document.getElementById("defaultPic").src = img;
}

function getImage2(){
var img = document.getElementById("subPic2").src;
document.getElementById("defaultPic").src = img;
 }
```

```css
*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
 }

 #defaultPic {
border: 1px solid black;
margin: 5px;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
 }

 #subPic1{
border: 1px solid black;
margin: 5px;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
  }

  #subPic2{
border: 1px solid black;
margin: 5px;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
  }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
     <title>TEST</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
 <script src="Image1.js"></script>
 <script src="Image2.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <img id="defaultPic" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/05/cc/e6/05cce60e8faed98dd28f77a3cfe13ef3.jpg" /><br/>
    <img id="subPic1" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/05/cc/e6/05cce60e8faed98dd28f77a3cfe13ef3.jpg" 
                  onclick="getImage1()"/><br/>
    <img id="subPic2" src="https://www.collabco.co.uk/media/1257/microsoft-logo1.jpg" 
                  onclick="getImage2()"/>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes, I have just discovered that the javascript is not enabled in Google Chrome.

Comment: Good!!..  check in other browsers also.. always verify your code in at least 2 browser.